Rendering UI Component at onclick
I am just working on a project, I just wanted to ask that can we do ui component rendering at onclick.
Example:
<div name="log-in" onclick={<Login/>}>                  
</div>

suppose that login component is created
I am just expecting a concise explanation, opinion regarding good practices or alternative in compare to what I was trying to do.

Sounds like you want a router.

so basically instead of doing this, router is a better option ?

hey guys, of course router is better ... use react-router
.... https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview

If all you want to do is show/hide an element on the page then you can control that with a state value.  Toggle the value in the onclick handler, conditionally show the element based on that value in the rendering.  The code shown simply doesn't make sense.

The onclick attribute should be a function, not a JSX element. In this case, React does not render the  component when the div is clicked. Instead, it just sets the onclick attribute to a JSX element, which isn't valid.
Correct Approach

Conditional Rendering with State

You can use React state to conditionally render components based on user interactions. Here’s how you can do it:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

function App() {
    const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
           <div name="log-in" onClick={() => setShowLogin(true)}>
             Click to log in
           </div>
            {showLogin && <Login />}
        </div>
     );
 }

 export default App;


Thanks alot ! It simplify my concepts of what I was trying to do.
